# Google Analytics Pages / Session is below 1 is that possible?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible for pages/session to be below 1 in google analytics?  If So, what is the valid reason why.  If it's not possible, what's the possible cause to investigate for it being below 1?

Background, we have a client whose analytics show that pages/session is 0.47 under the audience->mobile->overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can have a session without a pageview. For example if your application only tracks events and exceptions, you'll have a session but no pageviews.

You can also use screenviews instead of pageviews, which most mobiles apps do.

In your case, with a .47 pages/session rate, I'd guess it's just a mistake in implementation, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it.  Previous devs were tracking an event but never passing the pageview.  Thanks!